# Show horizontal progress bar while page is dowloading

Tags: jquery, html, css, progress-bar

Some time on website pages take time to download without user noticing it... Which in certain cases breaks the page functionality if user click on image of button which has some event handler attached to it.

I can use following code to show loading effect using image or some animation.

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
    $('#loading').fadeOut(2000);
});
```

For example this [link](http://designhuntr.com/demo/jQueryPageLoadingAnimation/index1.php)  is using common loading image file to show page progress.

What i want to add a horizontal progress bar which has width 100% and height about 10 pixels and is always floating at the bottom of page.

I am not sure how i can do that any ideas.. or example which i can look at

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adityap708/wz2c4/1/)

You can take a `div`, with the `10px height` and `0% width`. after that you can use `css` `transition` for 2 seconds and increase width of your div to 100%, it will appear as a progress bar.

Comment: I am looking for examples or ideas.. I dont want someone to do it for me.. I will try myself..

Comment: try it, it looks good and you dont have to use any plugin for it. it's a really simple way to do it

Comment: But i want to show page load progress in real time not based on times. I want to know if i can code this using jQuery Window.Load() event... and show progress bar accordingly